# Procedure for moving from MySQL Database to Jackrabbit

Tags: mysql, jcr, jackrabbit

I have a core Java Web application backed by the MySQL database. The total number of tables are quite few, may be 10 tables in total.
Now the plan is to move to the 'JCR' backend, esp. Jackrabbit.

Question:
1. How to design the JCR related nodes based on the tables in MySQL ?
2. The MySQL tables contains the Primary key, foreign keys, so how the JCR entities need to be designed so that the JCR entities knows their relationships between each other.

Pool your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

JCR is hierarchical and for content. Mapping relational tables 1:1 isn't the best approach. You want to look at your content/data and remodel it with the hierarchy in mind. Imagine you would be storing it in a filesystem.